# Adding data to JWT from the client-side

Tags: token, jwt, api-design

I'm new using JWTs. I have an API that generates a JWT for the clients to be authenticated for further requests. My JWT has a property that returns the user id:

```
{
  jwt: {
    exp: "2017-12-12 00:00:00",
    data: {
      user_id: 491
    }
  }
}
```

My question is if the client can decode the JWT generated by the API and add a new property into the data field, like this:

```
{
  jwt: {
    exp: "2017-12-12 00:00:00",
    data: {
      user_id: 491,
      status: 1
    }
  }
}
```

Or, if I can generate the JWT from the API auth system with the status field set to a default value and then the client could change it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The client can do that, but it would make the token invalid. When you change the content of the payload, e.g. add another field or change its content, the signature of the token no longer matches. When the API receives a token with invalid signature it should reject the token. Imagine if you had a field called `isAdmin` and the client could change it from `false` to `true`. It would make your authentication pointless; the client doesn't decide whether it's admin or not, the backend does.

When the token's payload changes the signature has to be remade. In order to sign the token, the client has to know the secret key (for H256). But the client shouldn't know the secret key.

So the answer is no, the client can't change the token.

You can read more about that [here](https://jwt.io/introduction/).

Comment: So, the only way to use fields that could change its value is to do it directly through the database from my API, i.e. if the user makes a request my API should query the DB to check for the status of that user, or there is another workaround that you could suggest?

Comment: The best would be if the content of the token never changed. Meaning that the backend should get everything needed in the token, from the DB, when it's issuing the initial token. If you want the payload of the token to change after creating the initial token, then the backend has to create a new token and issue that to the client.

Comment: Hmm... I guess that's not the best approach, I'm quite new in this topic of APIs auth, I guess I have to research a bit more to know what should I do. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In other words, you want to **tamper with your JWT token** and you cannot do it without **invalidating the token**.

The signature is calculated over the header and over the payload. The token issuer (the server) checks the signature to verify that the content has not been changed along the way.

Answer (score 1):

**In the latest Version of JWT Auth**

```
  $token = JWTAuth::claims(['account_id' => $account->id])->fromUser($user);
```

to data from token :

```
$payload = JWTAuth::getPayload();
$accountId = $payload->get('account_id');
```

**in the preview version of JWT auth**

```
 $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user, ['account_id' => $account->id]);
```

to data from token :

```
$payload = JWTAuth::getPayload(JWTAuth::getToken());
```